# Trying to set up a controller action as Xml endpoint

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I wanted to build a POX endpoint by using an ASP.NET MVC 2 controller action. I thought I would be able to reuse a lot of working code and be done in 15 min tops. I was wrong.
My action looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateInput(false)]
public ContentResult DoSomething(string xml)
```

The ValidateInput attribute is required because you'll get a nasty validation exception otherwise when posting Xml to the action.

The client code:

```
var req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(endPoint);
req.Method = "POST";
req.ContentType = "text/xml";
req.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate,sdch");
// ...open request, read response now
```

This is **working code**. The following request is sent to the endpoint (fiddler2)

```
POST http://doerak/Veekijker/Service.aspx/Melding HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: text/xml
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Host: theHost
Content-Length: 2220
Expect: 100-continue
Connection: Keep-Alive

Xml=theXml
```

However, when I remove the "Accept-Encoding" header from the client code, the xml string parameter of my controller action is null.

The request without the accept-encoding header looks like this

```
POST http://doerak/Veekijker/Service.aspx/Melding HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: text/xml
Host: theHost
Content-Length: 2220
Expect: 100-continue

Xml=theXml
```

How can I use my controller action, without having to set the Accept-Encoding header on the client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This for sure isn't `text/xml` that you're sending in the request body. It's a standard  form `name=value` pair.

Either:

- really send the data as XML blob (and that maybe needs an attribute at the method)
- or use the standard `Content-Type` that all HTML forms use (which is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`), and escape the value with URL encoding.