# Dynamic Wizard solution in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wizard, mvcsitemapprovider

I am using MVCSiteMapProvider in a MVC application to implement a wizard based workflow solution. The SiteMap file contains the nodes and branched representing different flows of the wizard. 
I have a model class that collects the selected data in the wizard pages (it is one simple class as there is only one item to select from each page). Every time the form gets submitted to the server, I look at what was the recent selection user made and route the model to an appropriate action method and return the associated view. 
I am planning to use one common routing controller and an action method where I will submit all my forms(all the wizard page), check from the model property where it has to be routed to and route to that action method using http WebRequest class as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270805/how-do-i-post-data-to-mvc-controller-using-httpwebrequest) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15385442/passing-data-between-different-controller-action-methods)
MVCSiteMap XML file contains the controller and action method names that I am planning to use for routing along with the model. I dont know how to create the controller object instance and its action using their string names.
Would this approach cause any performance issue. Please help/advise

Comment: I guess I can use TempData. But since it uses session, I want to see if there is any other better option

Comment: using a Cookie TempData Provider looks to be a viable solution as I want to stay away from using session for performance reasons.